# Setting iPhone lens position for focus

Tags: iphone, opencv, ios8, computer-vision, camera-calibration

This is for everyone out there having trouble getting consistent calibration parameters on iPhones. The old trick was to just focus your phone to infinity so that you can be sure you obtained a consistent camera matrix without recalibrating.

So the question is how come there isn't a method that allows you to manually set the focus for us plebs attempting computer vision applications.

Answer (score 0):

```
/*!
 @method setFocusModeLockedWithLensPosition:completionHandler:
 @abstract
    Sets focusMode to AVCaptureFocusModeLocked and locks lensPosition at an explicit value.

 @param lensPosition
    The lens position, as described in the documentation for the lensPosition property. A value of AVCaptureLensPositionCurrent can be used
    to indicate that the caller does not wish to specify a value for lensPosition.
 @param handler
    A block to be called when lensPosition has been set to the value specified and focusMode is set to AVCaptureFocusModeLocked. If
    setFocusModeLockedWithLensPosition:completionHandler: is called multiple times, the completion handlers will be called in FIFO order. 
    The block receives a timestamp which matches that of the first buffer to which all settings have been applied. Note that the timestamp 
    is synchronized to the device clock, and thus must be converted to the master clock prior to comparison with the timestamps of buffers 
    delivered via an AVCaptureVideoDataOutput. The client may pass nil for the handler parameter if knowledge of the operation's completion 
    is not required.

 @discussion
    This is the only way of setting lensPosition.
    This method throws an NSRangeException if lensPosition is set to an unsupported level.
    This method throws an NSGenericException if called without first obtaining exclusive access to the receiver using lockForConfiguration:.
*/
- (void)setFocusModeLockedWithLensPosition:(float)lensPosition completionHandler:(void (^)(CMTime syncTime))handler NS_AVAILABLE_IOS(8_0);
```

## HERE IT IS

A method provided by apple API in iOS8 to let you manually set the focus lens position.

## Some quick starter code

```
-(IBAction)focusAndLock:(id)sender
{
    if (self.isFocusLocked)
    {
         NSLog(@"unlock the lens");
        [[[self videoDeviceInput] device] setExposureMode:AVCaptureExposureModeAutoExpose];
        [[[self videoDeviceInput] device] setFocusMode:AVCaptureFocusModeAutoFocus];
        [self.focusAndLock setTitle:@"set Focus lock" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
        [self.focusAndLock setTitleColor:[UIColor blueColor] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
        self.isFocusLocked = NO;
    }
    else
    {
        NSLog(@"lock the lens");
        NSError *error;
        if ([[[self videoDeviceInput] device] lockForConfiguration:&error])
        {
            [[[self videoDeviceInput] device] setFocusModeLockedWithLensPosition:[[self videoDeviceInput] device].lensPosition completionHandler:nil];
            [[[self videoDeviceInput] device] setExposureMode:AVCaptureExposureModeLocked];
            [[[self videoDeviceInput] device] setFocusMode:AVCaptureFocusModeLocked];
            [self.focusAndLock setTitle:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"FOCUS LOCKED: %f",[[self videoDeviceInput] device].lensPosition] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
            [self.focusAndLock setTitleColor:[UIColor greenColor] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
            self.isFocusLocked = YES;
            NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
            NSString *documentsDirectory = [paths objectAtIndex:0];
            NSURL *selectedPath = [[NSURL alloc] initFileURLWithPath:[documentsDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"focusData.plist"]];
            NSMutableDictionary *focusDict = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] init];
            [focusDict setValue:[NSNumber numberWithFloat:[[self videoDeviceInput] device].lensPosition] forKey:@"focusLock"];
            [focusDict writeToURL:selectedPath atomically:YES];
        }
    }
}
```